# How can I change font size in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I want to resize down my whole Bootstrap project and I can't change font size. I'm using StarAdmin template.

I was trying to change font size in my **style.css**, but when I update "font-size", the website still apply old values.

```css
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.15;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

article, aside, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 0.8rem;  // <===== changed value but nothing happend
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

I would like to just change "basic" font size to resize my whole webpage.

Comment: "But when i change in this file "font-size" website reading still old values." — If the problem is that it is reading the old values, then your problem is about getting the browser to read the changes and has nothing to do with Bootstrap. If the problem is other styles overriding the font-size of the body element, then use the Developer tools in your browser to figure out what rules are setting the font size to the undesired values.

Comment: `rem` changes `font-size` relative to font-size of the root element and you are applying it to the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

Add important to all css properties which you want to override
see code for demo

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  font-size: 0.8rem !important;  // <===== Add Important
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff; }
```